# Format.exception C#/Asp.Net/SQL

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I am getting the error "System.FormatException : input string was not correct".

```
TextBox2.Text = objnm.rupees(Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(txtWOrds.Text.Trim())));
```

Comment: What is the value of `txtWOrds.Text`?

Comment: What do we have in `txtWOrds.Text` ? its better to use `decimal.TryParse` when you are not sure if it could be converted as `Convert` would return `null` which might fail later on.

Comment: @V4Vendetta `Convert` can't return null for value types

Comment: @V4Vendetta +1 for `.TryParse` suggestion!

Comment: @climbage yes that why i said might since i don't know the param for `obnjm.rupees`

Comment: @V4Vendetta That doesn't matter though,  `Convert.ToDecimal` can't return null, regardless of the signature for `rupees`, which is probably `Int64` otherwise he'd have a compile-time error.

Comment: As a side note: Why do you convert to Int64? If this is currency, it would be best to stick with `Decimal` so you don't loose any money!

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to convert it to decimal (`Convert.ToDecimal`) and then to Int64 (`Convert.ToIn64`).

Second, if `txtWOrds.Text` is not a number or is empty, than you will get this exception.  Make sure that it is a number.

Third, if your value is a number, than your problem likes somewhere in `objnm.rupees()`

Answer (score 1):

You should check the input in case its empty, like `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWOrds.Text)` then proceed with the parsing of the contents of the `textbox`.

Also you should be using `TryParse` which evaluates if the text can be parsed and if true you can use the value of the `out` parameter of this method.

In your case it could fail if the `TextBox` is empty.

Also if its anything related to money/currency not sure if you need the conversion to `Long` (seems like a mismatch there, please clarify. If you want a specific set of decimal points then it would be better to use `decimal.Round` )

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Convert.Int64` and just use `Convert.ToDecimal` (ideally you should use `decimal.TryParse`). Also, ensure that the input textbox contains the correct type (a decimal)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Decimal value = default(decimal);
  bool isValid = decimal.TryParse(txtWOrds.Text.Trim(), out value);
  if (isValid)
  {
        //your code using output 'value'             
  }
```